# Persistent download icon in Prestigio (4040 DUO multiphone) pull down menu - even with download over days ago. How to remove it?

Tags: downloading, notification-icons

In the pull down menu of my Prestigio 4040 DUO multiphone, there is this persistent DOWNLOAD icon, it's just stuck there even though download was completed days ago. It came when I was doing some app DOWNLOADS and has refused to go away even after downloads were long over.

On the top icon row of the phone, the animated download icon also shows, has been showing for days, even with no downloads.

Rebooting does not get rid of the icons. And if you press on it nothing happens. Does anyone know how to get rid of this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have android version 4.1 (jelly bean) or later, you can long-press on the notification and view the app settings page of the app that is showing the notification.

From there, you can force quit the app, or you can permanently disable notifications from that app.

At the very least, you'll know which app is causing the problem, and you may be able to change something within the app itself.